# phpoffice toArray return because of a vlookp formula

Tags: php, phpoffice

Here is a code to extract sheet data:

```
private function extractData($fileName)
{
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $reader->load($fileName);
    $sheets = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
    $sheetName = 'Sheet 1';  

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheetName);

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    // Slice away title, subtitle
    $rows = $objWorksheet->toArray();
    $headers = array_shift($rows);

    return [$rows, $headers];
}
```

which gives error:

```
BSC Dataset!F2 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured
vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php(2563): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell->getCalculatedValue()
#1 vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php(2639): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet->rangeToArray('A1:F4177', NULL, true, true, false)
```

The file in question has a vookup referencing another sheet on column F.

```
=IF($E2="Customer Pay Bonus Achievement",VLOOKUP($A2&$B2,$'Customer Pay Tracking'.$C:$V,5+$D2,0),VLOOKUP($A2&$B2,$'Wholesale+Counter'.$C:$X,5+$D2,0))
```